# Выдает ошибку в функции coppi при нахождении минимального элемента

Tags: c, массивы, динамические-массивы

Заполнить элементы двумерного массива натуральными числами. Из каждой нечётной (нумерация начинается с 0) строки удалить минимальный элемент. Количество чисел в строке может быть различным, последнее число - 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void inputRowsCols(int* rows) {
    printf("Enter the number of elements of the first array 'Row' ");
    while (scanf_s("%d", rows) != 1 || *rows <= 0 || getchar() != ('\n')) {
        printf("Enter the number of elements of the first array 'Row' \a");
        rewind(stdin);
    }
}

int** Matrix(int rows, int cols) {
    int** arr;
    arr = (int**)calloc(rows, sizeof(int*));//+
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int*)calloc(rows, sizeof(int));
    }
    if (arr == NULL) {
        printf("Ошибка выделения памяти");//ошибка выделения памяти
        return 0;
    }
    return arr;
}

int cols(int** arr, int row) {
    int cols = 1;
    for (int i = 0;; i++) {
        if (arr[row][i] != -100) {
            cols++;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return cols;
}

void printMatrix(int** arr, int rows) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols(arr, i); j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] != -100)
                printf("%5d", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void input_Matrix(int** arr, int rows, int* cols) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        int breakk = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < *cols && breakk == 0; j++) {
            printf("Input arr[%d][%d]: ", i + 1, j + 1);
            while (scanf_s("%d", &arr[i][j]) != 1 || getchar() != '\n') {
                if (arr[i][j] == -100) {
                    break;
                }
                printf("Enter element, row: %d, cols: %d ->", i + 1, j + 1);
                rewind(stdin);
            }
            if (arr[i][j] == -100) {
                breakk = 1;
                if (i != rows - 1) {
                    printf("Next row->\n");
                }
            }
            else {
                (*cols)++;
                arr[i] = (int*)realloc(arr[i], (*cols) * sizeof(int));
            }
        }
    }
}

//void delete_element_i(int i, int*** arr, int* size) {
//    for (i; i < (*size); i++) {
//        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
//    }
//    size--;
//    arr = (int*)realloc(arr, (*size) * sizeof(int));
//
//
//}
//void find(int*** arr, int rows,int cols) {
//    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
//        if (i % 2 == 1) {
//            int temp = 0;
//            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
//                if (arr[temp] > arr[j]) {
//                    temp = j;
//                }
//            }
//            delete_element_i(temp, arr, rows);
//        }
//       
//   }
//}
void coppi(int*** arr, int rows,int* cols) {
    printf("1");
    int temp=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
       
        if (i % 2 == 1 && cols != 0) {
          
            for (int j = 0; j < cols;j++) {
                if (arr[i][temp] > arr[i][j]) {
                    temp = j;
               }
                for (int k=temp; k < cols; k++) {
                    arr[i][k] = arr[i][k + 1];
                }
                *cols--;
                arr = (int*)realloc(arr, (*cols) * sizeof(int));
                
            }
        }
    }
}
int main() {


    int rows = 1, cols = 1;
    inputRowsCols(&rows);

    int** arr = Matrix(rows, cols);
    input_Matrix(arr, rows, &cols);

    printf("\n\nYour matrix -> \n");
    printMatrix(arr, rows);

    coppi(&arr, rows,cols);

    printf("\n\nNew matrix -> \n");
    printMatrix(arr, rows);

    free(*arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как я понимаю, "удалить" — это просто сдвинуть массив влево (поскольку последним элементом является 0)? Кстати, у вас при создании массива в каждой строке выделяется место для `rows` столбцов, а по логике надо для `cols`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас тут везде ошибки, а не только в функции `coppi()`. Вы не понимаете, как нужно работать с указателями.
Чисто по вопросу:

1. Вы передаете в функцию указатель, а потом идете в цикле счетчиком до значения указателя. При этом значение в нем что-то типа `0xFF237AFD98B07C3E`

```
void coppi(int*** arr, int rows, int* cols) 
{
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) 
            {
```

2. По условию задачи количество чисел в каждой строке - разное. А у вас общие размеры для всей матрицы `rows * cols` Циклы везде до значения `cols`,  а должны быть до нулевого элемента.

```
for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
//  а должно быть 
for (int j = 0; arr[i][j] != 0; j++)
```

3. Не имеет смысла проверять номер строки на четность. Проще сразу запустить цикл по нечетным строкам.

```
for (int i = 1; i < rows; i+=2)
```

4. Вот этой операцией вы уменьшили количество столбцов во всем массиве

```
*cols--;
```

5. При сдвиге вы выходите за границы массива

```
for (int k=temp; k < cols; k++)
    arr[i][k] = arr[i][k + 1];
```

6. А вот тут из-за того, что не умеете пользоваться указателями, вы убили весь ваш массив. Даже просто синтаксически посмотрите - `arr` имеет тип `int***`, а вы возвращаете `int*`. При этом, вам в общем-то не нужно реаллоцировать память - сдвинули элементы и всё.

```
arr = (int*)realloc(arr, (*cols) * sizeof(int));
```